# CAN bus off condition info

Tags: can-bus

When Bus off state occurs, assume because of failure of  can controller in one node, then how other nodes will come to know that the bus is in off state?
Can anybody aware of this?

Answer (score 1):

Bus off simply means that the current node stops sending information on the bus. Not necessarily that "the whole bus is off", though of course if there's some physical problem with the bus, then all nodes will end up in "bus off" state.

Other nodes will only notice this when a particular node stops responding and not doing ACK. Usually higher layer protocols have mechanisms for checking this, like for example the "Heartbeat" feature of CANopen.

For general CAN bus error handling see this: https://www.kvaser.com/about-can/the-can-protocol/can-error-handling/

Comment: So bus off in the sense, affected can node will be disconnected while other nodes will be communicated as usual on the bus? And the 128*11 bits waiting time or sw reset is for the reigniting the affected node instead of can bus.. It making me confuse totally.